# Why were most java.util.Date methods deprecated?

Tags: java, datetime, date, deprecated

When you look at the javadoc of the java.util.Date class, most of the methods are deprecated.  Why was this done?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, for two related reasons. It was a very poor implementation of the concept of Dates and Times and it was replaced by the `Calendar` class.

The `Calendar` class, although an improvement, leaves a lot to be desired as well, so for serious Date/Time work, everyone recommends [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) brings the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/), and intended to supplant the old Date/Calendar classes.

Edit: In response to the specific question of why the implementation is poor, there are many reasons. The JavaDoc sums it up as follows:

> Unfortunately, the API for these functions was not amenable to internationalization.

In addition to this general deficiency (which covers issues like the lack of a Time Zone component as well as the date formatting which is better handled in `DateFormat` and the inability to have a non-Gregorian calendar representation), there are specific issues which really hurt the `Date` class, including the fact that year is presented in an offset of 1900 from Common Era year.

`Calendar` has its own problems, but even as early as JDK 1.1 it was obvious that `java.util.Date` was not going to cut it. Even though `Calendar` is arguable the worst JDK API, it has taken until version 7 to attempt to address it.

Comment: Cleanly making the transition from inadequate to incomprehensible in jdk 1.1 :)

Comment: Also the 'Date' class was named poorly. They should have called it a Time, or DateTime.

Answer (score 17):

- `Date` is mutable
- `Date` doesn't have support for time zones

The latter led to it being replaced by `Calendar`. And the former, combined with the ease-of-use, lead to both being replaced by [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) / [JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/) ([java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html))

Comment: Thank you IBM for Calendar, DateFormatter and all the other associated crap. Another brilliant example of overengineering without actually solving the problem at hand.

Answer (score 11):

They're deprecated because Date was written as fast as possible back in the day when they wanted to rush the JDK out the door.

It turns out the Dates and Calendars are Hard. So, they created the Calendar class, which much more thought, in order to handle the Hard Parts of working with calendars.

They deprecated the Date methods and delegated to Calendar because they didn't want to change the behavior of the existing Date methods, and possibly break existing applications.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good answer straight from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

> A long-standing bugbear of Java developers has been the inadequate support for the date and time use cases of ordinary developers.
>
> For example, the existing classes (such as `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormatter`) aren’t thread-safe, leading to potential concurrency issues for users—not something the average developer would expect to deal with when writing date-handling code.
>
> Some of the date and time classes also exhibit quite poor API design. For example, years in `java.util.Date` start at 1900, months start at 1, and days start at 0—not very intuitive.
>
> ... `java.util.Date` represents an instant on the timeline—a wrapper around the number of milli-seconds since the UNIX epoch—but if you call toString(), the result suggests that it has a time zone, causing confusion among developers.

Comment: It seems the author didn't bother to proofread his article. As of Java's [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) online documentation, days start at `1` and months start at `0`. Both correspond with the UNIX API, see [time.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the official reason why it has been deprecated, but as far as I can tell `GregorianCalendar`and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) support operations on dates, meaning that you can add, for instance, a day to a date and have its month and year updated accordingly.

For instance, say you want to compute the day after the current date and today is May 31st; with `java.util.Date`, you just have `getDays() +1`, which returns 32, and you have to handle the knowledge that the current month doesn't have 32 days by yourself; with `GregorianCalendar`or Joda.time, adding a day to May 31st results in an object representing June 1st, hiding the complexity from your sight.

Comment: Your example is not a problem with the Date object, but with the code using it. GregorianCalendar would do the exact same thing. So that entire point is moot.