# What's the most efficient way to strip out the time from a Java Date object?

Tags: java, date

What's the most efficient way to remove the time portion from a Java date object using only Classes from within the JDK?

I have the following

> myObject.getDate() =
>   {java.util.Date}"Wed May 26 23:59:00
>   BST 2010"

To reset the time back to 00:00:00, I'm doing the following

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(myObject.getDate()));
```

The output is now

> myDate = {java.util.Date}"Wed May 26
>   00:00:00 BST 2010"

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Consider JODA Time. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ ; much more pleasant to work with. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901262/why-were-most-java-util-date-methods-deprecated

Comment: Not an option for me I'm afraid. I'm working with a third party app that won't allow for additional jars to be added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More verbose, but probably more efficient:

```
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    // cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);   // As jarnbjo pointed out this isn't enough
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Also, you don't need to worry about locale settings, which may cause problems with string to date conversions.

Comment: I've just tried this out and I get the following output myDate = {java.util.Date}"Wed May 26 12:00:00 BST 2010"

Comment: Are you perhaps formatting the date in 12h instead of a 24h setting?

Comment: I'm getting a Date object out of cal by calling cal.getTime()

Comment: `GregorianCalendar.getInstance();` does nothing other than `Calendar.getInstance();`. It's a static method of the Calendar class, this is just an unnecessary import.

Comment: You must use cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0). Calendar.HOUR is just the 12-hour-field of the calendar and will leave the AM_PM field unchanged, causing the 24-hour-field to be set to either 0 or 12.

Comment: `GregorianCalendar.getInstance();` is not the same as `Calendar.getInstance();`. The later takes the current timezone and locale into account and may return something different than GegorianCalendar.

Comment: @whiskeysierra, `GregorianCalendar` doesn't declare any `getInstance` methods, so `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()` is just an odd way of invoking `Calendar.getInstance()`. In my opinion these "indirect" static invocations shouldn't have be allowed and should be avoided.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Apache commons, you can use [DateUtils.truncate()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#truncate%28java.util.Date,%20int%29):

```
Date myDate = DateUtils.truncate(myObject.getDate(), Calendar.DATE)
```

<sup>(If you don't have access to Apache Commons, DateUtils.truncate() is implemented basically the same as [kgiannakakis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566181/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-strip-out-the-time-from-a-java-date-object/3566260#3566260).)</sup>

---

Now, if you want "clever" code that is very fast, and you don't mind using deprecated functions from `java.util.Date`, here is another solution. (Disclaimer: I wouldn't use this code myself. But I have tested it and it works, even on days when DST starts/ends.)

```
long ts = myObject.getDate().getTime() - myObject.getDate().getTimezoneOffset()*60000L;
Date myDate = new Date(ts - ts % (3600000L*24L));
myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + myDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60000L);
```

Answer (score 1):

These methods are deprecated, but given a `Date`, you can do something like this:

```
Date d = ...;
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
```

You should use a [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) if possible. You'd then use the `cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)`, etc.

It should be mentioned that if it's at all an option, you should use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

#### Related questions

- [Why were most `java.util.Date` methods deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901262/why-were-most-java-util-date-methods-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking time zone into consideration? I see you have BST right now, but what when BST is over? Do you still wish to use BST?

Anyway, I'd suggest you have a look at [`DateMidnight`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) from [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and use that.

Things may vary depending on how you want to handle the time zones. But in it's simplest form, it should be as simple as:

```
DateMidnight d = new DateMidnight(myObject.getDate());
```

If you *must* convert back go `java.util.Date`:

```
Date myDate = d.toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()-myDate.getTime()%86400000)
```

might do the trick. Talk about quick&dirty.

Comment: haha, I knew that would cost me a few reputation score, but SCNR