# Why has java.util.Date been deprecated?

Tags: java, deprecated, java.util.date

I apologize if this is like a dumb question, especially for all of you super-professional programmers out there.  I am just beginning to program in Java, and I am starting to do basic things like scheduling procedures which requires comparing the current time to specific times that I have selected to execute certain procedures.

Basically I need a way to get and manipulate date-time objects.  The first thing that comes up in may searches (and many answers on SO) is the `java.util.Date` object.  It seems like this is perfect and has all the basic functions that I need.  I like that I can get the current date-time with simple `new Date()`.  Then when creating other date-time objects, I can  use the `.getYear()`, `.getDate()`, and other methods.  The `.before()` and `.after()` functions are also very useful for what I am trying to do.

Anyway, my question is: **why has most of this package been deprecated?**  This is part of the core java.util package.  It is something very important to many programs.  I have found newer alternatives like `GregorianCalendar` and `Joda.time`, not knowing which one will be better for me in the long run.  It seems like it would be nice to just use the core `java.util.date` and move on.  I get the deprecated warnings in my IDE which makes me think maybe this isn't the best thing to do.

I am just trying to understand why this package is not supported anymore, as a humble programmer looking for answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901262/why-were-most-java-util-date-methods-deprecated?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901264/1862502

Comment: Neither the class nor 'this package' has been deprecated, and deprecation does not imply 'not supported any more'. Accuracy please.