# Changing the date

Tags: java, date

Basically, I've got a little program that uses date.

```
Date current = new Date();
current.setDate(current.getDay() + time1);
```

When I do this it adds to the day, but say time1 = 30 then the month doesn't change when I print the date out. I hope this makes sense I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: use .getDate instead of .getDay .

The value returned by getDay is an integer corresponding to the day of the week: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

Comment: A lot of the Date methods are deprecated. Calendar has a roll() function that does what you're looking for, but I highly recommend looking into Joda Time. (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: You are using a deprecated `Date`method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901262/why-were-most-java-util-date-methods-deprecated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add one day to a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to perform date arithmetic and a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to display the result. Something like,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
 public static Date addDaystoGivenDate(Integer days, Date date){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```