# Why Date.UTC() is deprecated? What do I use in Android instead?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

The docs say that [Date.UTC()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#UTC(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) is deprecated and should be replaced with some untrivial spell with `Calendar` (magic phrase, I mean). A bit more extensive search tells me that the proposed remedy is no better and `Calendar` is arguably the worst JDK API.

Finally I found [joda-time-android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android).

But what I have not [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-date-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead) is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901262/why-were-most-java-util-date-methods-deprecated) concise, simple explanation (and not an obscure reference to "internationalization problems"):

1) ***Why `Date` is bad***,

2) ***Why `Date.UTC()` is bad***, and

3) ***Why `Calendar` & friends are bad***.

***These classes may have problems for the general case, but probably they are ok for my specific problem?***

For example, Date is mutable, it is wrong in the long run, but I myself can live with that right now. Yes, the ranges are crazy, but after I add/subtract 1, will I have other problems?

(What I need right now boils down to an alarm-clock that works across time zones. No dates-without-time or dates-in-documents, leap seconds are irrelevant.)

**EDIT** Folks, I understand that this question and [Should I use Java date and time classes or go with a 3rd party library like Joda Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda) are roughly about the same topic, but the questions are different:

1) Android means restricted resources, therefore there is a counter-argument of 100+ classes in the .apk

2) My question is different: the question *Why Date/Calendar is bad?* means that I want to know what problems will be there if I decide to use these classes. I want a concise explanation of the *reasons* behind the story with these date/time classes.

Comment: No, the proposed remedy *is* better. `Calendar` is still a bad API, but using that to create an object based on calendrical values is certainly better than `Date`, and while the API for `Calendar` still uses 0-based months (urgh) at least the *year* is sane...

Comment: I go into some details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar/344400#344400 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda/589940#589940