# Cannot deduct a day from current date in Java using jodatime

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I use `JodaTime` to deduct a day from current date . But it dosen't work for me, which means, my Date remains same, nothing is deducted! .

Here is the code ,

```
public class Note {
    private java.sql.Date date;

    public java.sql.Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(java.sql.Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}


Note notez=new Note();

notez.setDate(new java.sql.Date(new DateTime(new  Date()).minus(1).toDate().getTime()));
```

Have any ideas about this .

Thank you.

Comment: new DateTime(new  Date()) could be changed to DateTime.now() if that helps clear things up. (also, specifying a timezone is likely warranted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
notez.setDate(new java.sql.Date(new DateTime(new  Date()).minusDays(1).toDate().getTime()));
```

Comment: just for clearness: you mean `notez.setDate(new java.sql.Date(new DateTime(new  java.util.Date()).minusDays(1).toDate().getTime()));` ?

Comment: Yes I mean java.util.Date, but, actually, I just copied the last line of code and corrected it.

Comment: Thank both of you.

Comment: I strongly suggest passing a time zone [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) to that `DateTime` constructor. Otherwise your results may vary at runtime depending on the JVM’s current default time zone (which can change at any moment).

Answer (score 4):

DateTime.minus(long) will deduct the amount of milliseconds passed to the method.

What you're looking for is DateTime.minusDays(int)

Check the [Javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use 
java.util.Calendar & java.util.Date instead.

it works easy like this

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
```

...

```
    Date today = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTime(today); 
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); //-1 parameter indicates number of days you wish to add/deduct,
    Date yesterday = c.getTime();



notez.setDate(yesterday);
```

Comment: Because the j.u.Date / j.u.Calendar apis are bad and Joda Time is superior in every way?

Comment: Don't think so i Had the Same issue using joda time i could not get it to work with joda but the Java.util. Api s Are the best no 3rd party Library to add and many more advantages.  so this was the best Solution for me if it's so easy why don't You Provide an answer

Comment: [Many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) [people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) [disagree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901262/why-were-most-java-util-date-methods-deprecated). Also, I won't provide an answer to the question above because there were other people doing it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalDate`

A `java.sql.Date` represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone. Unlike the unfortunately-named `java.util.Date` which represents both a date and a time-of-day.

The appropriate Joda-Time class would be [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).

While a `LocalDate` stores no time zone, a time zone is crucial in determining ‘today’. Just after midnight in Paris is still ‘yesterday’ in Montréal.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zone );
LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays( 1 );
```

Convert to a java.sql type. The `LocalDate::toString` method generates text formatted according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, YYYY-MM-DD. For a date-only values that happens to be the same as in SQL format expected by the `java.sql.Date.valueOf` method.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( yesterday.toString() );
```

By the way… if, instead of Joda-Time, you were using the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later, the code would be nearly the same as shown here. The makers of Joda-Time have asked us to migrate to java.time as soon as is convenient.